# Script Task in SSIS package to FTP

Tags: vb.net, ssis

All,

I have an SSIS package (Sql Server 2008), that does a few data flow and file operations and then finally uploads the file to an FTP Server.

I was able to get most of the work done, but one last critical piece. Using 'Data Flow' a text file is generated with data from the database. Now that file is zipped with a timestamp at the end Ex: "filename_08132012.zip".

The timestamp changes every day, so its a new file every time to upload to the FTP server. So, instead of "FTP Task" (I could not figure out a way to make this work), I have a "Script Task" that looks for a file with today's date and uploads it to the FTP server. Following is the code, but I have two questions related to this:

1. I want this "Script Task" to pick up that day's file ex: filename_08132012.zip, filename_08142012.zip. I have the code to convert date to string with proper format. But for some reason, it is not.
2. How to step through the execution of this script file, the was Visual Studio allows for VB.net code? This script task GUI is not allowing to step through.
3. It uploads an empty file to the FTP server. A file with 0 bytes. How do I troubleshoot this?

```vb
' Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
' Write scripts using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008.
' The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

<System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version:="1.0", Publisher:="", Description:="")> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
Enum ScriptResults
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
End Enum


Public Sub Main()
    '
    ' Add your code here
    '

    Try

        'Create the connection to the ftp server

        Dim cm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections.Add("FTP")

        'Set the properties like username & password

        cm.Properties("ServerName").SetValue(cm, "172.24.97.21")

        cm.Properties("ServerUserName").SetValue(cm, "bbxuser")

        cm.Properties("ServerPassword").SetValue(cm, "blockbuster")

        cm.Properties("ServerPort").SetValue(cm, "21")

        cm.Properties("Timeout").SetValue(cm, "0") 'The 0 setting will make it not timeout

        cm.Properties("ChunkSize").SetValue(cm, "1000") '1000 kb

        cm.Properties("Retries").SetValue(cm, "1")

        'create the FTP object that sends the files and pass it the connection created above.

        Dim ftp As FtpClientConnection = New FtpClientConnection(cm.AcquireConnection(Nothing))

        'Connects to the ftp server

        ftp.Connect()

        'Build a array of all the file names that is going to be FTP'ed (in this case only one file)

        Dim files(0) As String


        Dim FileDate As Date
        FileDate = System.DateTime.Today

        files(0) = "D:\NCR\Apps\RBX.SSIS.BBX_Customer_Extract\Email_Campaign\Redbox_EmailCampaign_and_Analytics_Extract_" + FileDate.ToString("mmddyyyy") + ".zip"

        'ftp the file

        'Note: I had a hard time finding the remote path directory. I found it by mistake by creating both the FTP connection and task in the SSIS package and it defaulted the remote path setting in the FTP task.

        ftp.SendFiles(files, "/Email Campaign", True, False) ' the True makes it overwrite existing file and False is saying that it is not transferring ASCII

        ftp.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure

    End Try

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You're better off having a 'staging' folder that the file sits in. Then you can probably use a for each file to pick up _any_ file in that folder and pass it to the FTP task then move it out of the staging folder so it's not sent again

Answer (score 1):

Right after I wrote the question out, I figured a couple of things out.

1. I used the incorrect format. Correct format is FileDate.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".zip"

```vb
files(0) = "D:\NCR\Apps\RBX.SSIS.BBX_Customer_Extract\Email_Campaign\Redbox_EmailCampaign_and_Analytics_Extract_" + FileDate.ToString("mmddyyyy") + ".zip"
files(0) = "D:\NCR\Apps\RBX.SSIS.BBX_Customer_Extract\Email_Campaign\Redbox_EmailCampaign_and_Analytics_Extract_" + FileDate.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".zip"
```

1. (see above)
2. I just found this and it works: [Troubleshoot Script Task](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/e4362d4c-80fa-459b-8030-48f66e2a8664)
3. Solving 1 & 2, solves 3